# Django production server error 13 while saving a pickure

Tags: python, django, django-views

so I start making a server to help a school project and I have not found the answer to these questions.
In general the code works like these when you first open the site and register an account, the system will check if the account exists. If not then it will create It and make an cracha for it, that is basically an image, but in the production server with apache, I can not save the image that the system generates. The server is running in a raspberry machine with ubunto server, I set up the permissions 777 to the media folder that is where the system save the cracha image and a 
 `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R base_directory/` and  `chmod 777 -R Base_directory`

**views**:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        senha1 = EncritpPassword(request.POST.get('senha', 'error'))
        senha2 = EncritpPassword(request.POST.get('senha-r', 'error'))
        Email = request.POST.get('email', 'erro')
        nome = request.POST.get('nome', 'erro')
        comite = request.POST.get('SelectionCommitee', 'No Committee')
        NOW = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        if ( (senha1 != 'error') and (senha2 != 'error') and (senha1 == senha2) and (Email != 'erro') and (nome != 'erro')):
            user = CheckUser(Email)
            if user == False:
                UserProtocol = EncritpEPR(Email)
                Cracha_Generator(UserProtocol, nome, comite)
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    messages.success(request, 'Success creating your account now login please!')
                    UserRegister(nome, Email, comite, NOW)
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO index_account ( nome, email, senha, committees, createdAt, autorizacao) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 0)", [nome, Email, senha2, comite, NOW] )
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO index_Conference (UserProtocol, email, rooms, datetime, AditionalInformation) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", [UserProtocol , Email, 'no_data', 'no_data', 'no_data'])
                    return redirect('/user/login')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error 401: This User alredy exist in our system!!!!')
                return redirect('/user/login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Erro 409: the passwords MUST be Equal')
            return redirect('/user/register')
    User_email = request.session.get('email', 'erro')
    if User_email !="erro":
        messages.error(request, 'Error 401: Why another account?')
    return render(request, 'account/register.html')
```

**cracha_generator:**

```
def Cracha_Generator(protocol, Full_Name, Committee):

    #caminhos
    Qr_Code_path = ('media/qr-code-' + protocol + '.png')
    Cracha_path = 'media/cracha.png'
    Cracha_pronto_path = 'media/cracha/cr'+ protocol + '.png'

    data = ('SOME_URL' + protocol )# o que vai dentro do qrcode

    # dimensoes do qr code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1, # tamanho da informacao
        box_size=7, # tamanho do qrcode 7 = 217x217px
        border=1 #tamanho da borda
    )


    qr.add_data(data) #coloca dentro do qr code
    qr.make(fit=True) # faz o qrcode

    img = qr.make_image(fill='white', background_color='black') # faz a imagem com cores
    img.save(Qr_Code_path) # salva a imagem

    cracha = Image.open(Cracha_path)    #abre a primeira imagem
    qrcodeImage = Image.open(Qr_Code_path)#abre a segunda imagem

    area = (550, 265) # define um poto inicial para colar a imagem

    cracha.paste(qrcodeImage, area) # cola a imagem com a area expecificada

    image = cracha

    font_type = ImageFont.truetype('media/times-new-roman.ttf', 24) # fonte com tamanho
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image) # indica qual imagem escrever
    draw.text(xy=(205, 45), text=Full_Name, fill=(0,0,0), font=font_type) # escreve
    draw.text(xy=(205, 110), text=Committee, fill=(0,0,0), font=font_type) # escreve
    draw.text(xy=(205, 175), text=protocol, fill=(0,0,0), font=font_type)# escreve
    image.save(Cracha_pronto_path)# salva

    registro(Full_Name, 'media/cracha/cr'+ protocol + '.png', protocol ) # registro de tarefa em arquivo registro.dll

    os.remove(Qr_Code_path) # exclui sobras do sistema
    return True # termina a funcao
```

Comment: the comments are in portuguese, sorry for that,  I am brazilian

Comment: You may want to learn about the concept of "current working directory", and how relative file path are resolved relatively (surprise surprise) to the current working directory. Hint: always use absolute path (why do you think you have to configure the media root path in your settings ?).  Also (mostly unrelated but) by all means, __use django's features (Models, Forms etc)__.

Comment: thank you, I will work hard to learn. but I do not found anything like this in the documentation, and I am trying to solve this problem in the past 3 moths so, anyway thankyou so much